# kvm lubuntu has no disk space

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu

I've installed kvm, created a new image for virtual host:

```
sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 /var/lib/libvirt/images/lubuntu.img 30G
```

created an .xml configuration file for it:

```
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>lubuntu</name>
  <uuid>f5b8c05b-9c7a-3211-49b9-2bd635f7e2aa</uuid>
  <memory>10485760</memory>
  <currentMemory>10485760</currentMemory>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <os>
    <type>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/>
  </features>
  <clock offset='utc'/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type="file" device="disk">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/lubuntu.img"/>
      <target dev="vda" bus="virtio"/>
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x04" function="0x0"/>
    </disk>
    <disk type="file" device="cdrom">
      <driver name="qemu" type="raw"/>
      <source file="/var/lib/libvirt/images/lubuntu-17.04-desktop-i386.iso"/>
      <target dev="hdc" bus="ide"/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type="drive" controller="0" bus="1" target="0" unit="0"/>
    </disk>
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <source bridge='virbr0'/>
      <mac address="00:00:A3:B0:56:10"/>
    </interface>
    <controller type="ide" index="0">
      <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x00" slot="0x01" function="0x1"/>
    </controller>
    <input type='mouse' bus='ps2'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' autoport="yes" listen='0.0.0.0'/>
    <console type='pty'>
      <target port='0'/>
    </console>
  </devices>
</domain>
```

started it by:

```
virsh create lubuntu.xml
```

after i connect to it using vnc viewer and see the installation windows, but when i click "install" i see warning, that i don't have enough disk space

```
This pc has only 262.7 kB free.
```

my lubuntu.img file is exactly this size and i can't fix. When i do:

```
valera@ubuntu-server:/var/lib/libvirt/images$ sudo qemu-img resize lubuntu.img +5G
Image resized.
```

it remains still 200+ kB size...

Comment: You used `type="raw"` in the xml for the qcow2 img...

Comment: thx, that was the problem :) changed to qcow2 and now it works!

Comment: @TomYan Please post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used `type="raw"` in the xml for the qcow2 image lubuntu.img. Changing it to `type="qcow2"` fixes the problem.